# Magento 404 front end on Multi Site after moving server

Tags: magento, mod-rewrite, server, http-status-code-404, dedicated

We have recently moved a Magento multi site environment to a new dedicated server, however all the sites apart from the admin URL site (not used apart from admin are) are reporting Magento style 404 pages on the front end.

We have ensured mod_rewrite is turned on, checked the database and manually amended the URLs in PHPMyAdmin to assign some temporary test URLs. The URL assigned to the admin area works fine, and the rest resolve to the server, however every front end is still 404. We have tried adding in index.php to the URL, no change. Checked all file and folder permissions, all OK. Cleared all cache manually and reindexed from command line. No change.

We have checked HTACCESS is correct which it looks to be. We have even taken another backup of the database and full site and restored to another server with the same issues.

We have also tried disabling SEO urls/URL Rewrites without change too.

Error logs dont say a lot either which isnt helpful.

Really struggling with this now so any help or pointers greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**First Solution:**

Replace current .htaccess file with the default .htaccess file from Magento.

**Second Solution:**

```
#fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
```

If doesn't work, try following solution:

**Third Solution:**

1. Is this installed on an Apache webserver? If not, the .htaccess functions will need to be translated to your flavor of web server software.
2. Has DSO module for `mod_rewrite` been installed in Apache and been enabled to load?
3. Is `AllowOverrides` enabled for the virtual server so `Options +FollowSymLinks` will function? You may have to check with your hosting service provider and have it enabled.
4. Is Magento's .htaccess file available in the doc root folder?
5. Has the rewrite engine been turned on in the .htaccess file?
6. Has the proper RewriteBase been assigned in the .htaccess file?

General entries in Magento's .htaccess that must function so rewrites will function to eliminate the need for index.php to appear in the URL.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
############################################
## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root
    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Third solution from [Fiasco Labs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/553/fiasco-labs)